# How to print the alphabet one after the other and extend this

Tags: python

I have my alphabet and would like it to continue one after the other

as an example:

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
...
```

When this happens from "a" to "z" I want my code to add a letter to it.

as an Example:

```
"aa"
"ab"
"ac"
"ad"
...
```

And wanted wanted to ask if this works with variables

EDIT for comment
My code (for now):

```
import time


char_abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
char_ABC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

for i in char_abc:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
for j in char_ABC:
    print(j)
    time.sleep(0.1)

# for a in char_abc + char_ABC: #
#   print(a)                    # This is only a test
#   time.sleep(0.1)             #
```

to solve the misunderstanding i have deleted my sentence for the ord() function to only deal with the variables

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to ask about the `ord()` function or `char_abc` variable. Perhaps you can share some code you're using?

Comment: but of course it is possible, this is also my first question that refers to a code, I try to present it well :) have added this as an edit to the actual question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that yields the cartesian product of increasing lengths of the alphabet.

I use `itertools.count` to keep track of a counter starting at 1 and incrementing everytime the outerloop restarts. Then the inner loop is in charge of generating the actual letter combinations via `itertools.product`

```py
def cycle_abc():
    char_abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in itertools.count(1):
            for combo in itertools.product(char_abc, repeat=i):
                    yield "".join(combo)

for letters in cycle_abc():
    print(letters)

# a
# b
# c
# ...
# aa
# ab
# ac
# ...
# ba
# bb
# bc
# ...
```

Comment: wow, that actually simpler than I thought ! thank you! and a second thank you to the short explanation!

Comment: Awesome! Since this worked for you, do you mind selecting this answer as correct so that others with the same/similar question can find it?

Comment: totally! that's the least!